# ASP.NET [How to check if SqlDataSource1 is empty]

Tags: asp.net

I make SqlDataSource1.DataBind(); with some parameters on button click,

then I'm working with a Grid onDataBound();

but if my SqlDataSource1 returns empty data I've got an error even if I'm trying to check if (GridView2.HeaderRow.Cells.Count != 0) so I guess I need to check it on SqlDataSource1 someway.

Question : How ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridView2.HeaderRow is null when when the data source is null so you could try checking if **GridView2.HeaderRow = null**

Answer (score 0):

I would check `GridView2.Rows.Count` instead. Maybe there are no HeaderRow cells when the data source is empty.

Comment: I'm not sure I have access to rows - count when datasource is empty, but previous answer works for sure.

Comment: Row count should be zero after DataBind() on the GridView, but either way, it's good that you have a solution that works.